# What's wrong with my LRUCache code

Tags: java, caching, data-structures, lru

I try to solution a question in [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/#/description),it's ask to implement a LRUCache.
And when I submit my code, the System told me the result is Wrong Answer.[image]
Because the TestCase is too long ,I can't find the problem in my code.And when I choice "Run code" to sumbit my code,it's correct.
[image]

Here is my code

```
public class LRUCache {
    private int capacity;
    private int size;
    private HashMap<Integer, Node> cache = new HashMap<>();
    private Node tail;
    private Node head;
    public LRUCache(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        size = 0;
        tail = new Node(-1, -1);
        head = new Node(-1, -1);
        tail.setPrev(head);
        head.setNext(tail);
    }
    public Integer get(int key) {
        Integer value = -1;
        Node old = cache.get(key);
        if (old != null){
            //move to tail
            Node node = new Node(key, old.getValue());
            removeNode(old);
            moveToTail(node);
            value = node.getValue();
        }
        return value;
    }
    public void put(int key, int value) {
        Node n = new Node(key, value);
        Node old = cache.get(key);
        boolean isExist = old != null;
        if (isExist){
            removeNode(old);
            size--;
        }
        //move to tail
        moveToTail(n);
        cache.put(key, n);
        size++;
        //remove node if size upper than capacity
        while (capacity < size){
            Node rm = head.getNext();
            cache.remove(rm.getKey());
            removeNode(rm);
            size--;
        }
    }

    private void removeNode(Node node){
        if (node.getPrev() != head){
            node.getPrev().setNext(node.getNext());
            node.getNext().setPrev(node.getPrev());
        }else {
            head.setNext(node.getNext());
            node.getNext().setPrev(head);
        }
        node = null;
    }

    private void moveToTail(Node node){
        node.setPrev(tail.getPrev());
        tail.getPrev().setNext(node);
        tail.setPrev(node);
        node.setNext(tail);
    }

    private class Node{
        private int key;
        private int value;
        private Node prev;
        private Node next;

        public Node(int key, int value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.prev = null;
            this.next = null;
        }

        public int getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public Node getPrev() {
            return prev;
        }

        public void setPrev(Node prev) {
            this.prev = prev;
        }

        public Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node next) {
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: were you able to get the code working ?

Comment: @zenwraight yes,when I click the Run Code button in LeetCode,the result is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is problem in your get and put methods. Every time you are creating new nodes. Ideally it should be the same node moved across the DLL. Also, the node should have a setValue() method for updates.

The following update should work.

```
public Integer get(int key) {
    Integer value = -1;
    Node old = cache.get(key);
    if (old != null){
        //move to tail
        /////Node node = new Node(key, old.getValue());
        removeNode(old);
        moveToTail(old);
        value = old.getValue();
    }
    return value;
}
public void put(int key, int value) {
    Node n = null;
    n = cache.get(key);
    if (n != null){
        //Update the value of node and move
        n.setValue(value);
        removeNode(n);
        size--;
    }
    else {
       n = new Node(key, value);
    }

    //move to tail
    moveToTail(n);
    cache.put(key, n);
    size++;
    //remove node if size upper than capacity
    while (capacity < size){
        Node rm = head.getNext();
        cache.remove(rm.getKey());
        removeNode(rm);
        size--;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: you are right,I just find the mistake that I change the new node's prev and next but didn't save it into HashMap